# Html.DropDownListFor returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

There are similar questions and I have tried most of them. Instead of continuing to destroy the remaining code while conjuring demons from the similar past questions, I have decided to ask for help.

When I arrive at the AddMembership action I get a null value instead of the selected item. Below are the details.

**View**;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMembership", "WorkSpace", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "true", id = "frmAddMembership" }))
{
 <div id="newMembershipDiv">

     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedID, new SelectList(Model.allInfo, "Value","Text",1), "Select!")
     <input type="submit" value="Add" name="Command" /> 
 </div> 
}
```

**Controller** (I just want to see the selectedID or anything appear here.);

```
public ActionResult AddMembership(SelectListItem selectedID)
{
  return View();
}
```

**Model**;

```
public class SomeModel
{ 
    public SelectList allInfo { get; set; } 
    public SelectListItem selectedID { get; set; } 
}
```

**The Monstrosity which initializes the allInfo SelectList**

```
model.allInfo = new SelectList(synHelper.getall().ToArray<Person>().Select(r => new SelectListItem {Text=r.Name, Value=r.prID.ToString() }));
```

synHelper.getAll() returns a List of the below class;

```
public class Person
{    
    public Guid prID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that is posted to your action is a `selectedID`, which is a simple string. If you wander, in the request it looks as simple as:

```
selectedID=1234
```

Therefore it should be awaited for as a simple string. Adjust your action parameter:

```
public ActionResult AddMembership(string selectedID)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one other quick question though. If I wanted to send the whole Person object to the action, what changes would I have to do? Doing something like "@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m" gives me a null value error.

Comment: on an added note, I get an empty string when I make your change.